# Possible to access DbConfiguration from DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Having my own EF [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext) derived class associated with my own [`DbConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration) derived configuration class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
}
```

I'm trying to access the instance of the `MyDbConfiguration` from within `MyDbContext`.

(Assuming that there actually *is* any instance at all).

E.g.:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        // This lines fails to compile:
        var config = (MyDbConfiguration)Configuration;

        config.SomeProperty = 42;
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration' to 'MyDbConfiguration'.

Obviously, there is no direct relationship beween these two types.

Most likely I'm completely misunderstanding this Entity Framework configuration stuff and this question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Still I'm kindly trying to ask it:

**My question:**

Is there any way to access the `DbConfiguration` from within a `DbContext`?

If not, is it possible the other way around? I.e. access the `DbContext` from within a `DbConfiguration`?

(This question is related to [EFCache issue #14](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache/issues/14))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being unable to find a direct answer, [a workaround suggested by the EFCache author](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache/issues/14#issuecomment-312471064) helped me in my situation:

> Just store a reference to the cache in a static variable before you pass it to the `CacheTransactionHandler` c'tor and then you should be able to it access from anywhere. The cache is effectively singleton so I don't think there is any problem with doing this.

Not the best solution I was hoping for and stil runs perfectly.